# Annotation based user retrieval Spring security

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-annotations

I was looking for proper way how to recieve active/logged in user. I use Spring Security 3.1 with the same version of Spring MVC.
The whole idea is based on [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8764545/best-practice-for-getting-active-users-userdetails) which was more commented in the article :

[@ActiveUser annotation from the article](http://blog.awnry.com/post/16187851956/spring-mvc-get-the-logged-in-userdetails-from-your)

I completely follow the instructions but I still get this kind of error :

```
No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User.<init>()]
```

In my applicationContext.xml I have those three annotations which were not directly proposed by the author of

```
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="my.package.*" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

What could cause this kind of problem?

Answer (score 1):

After hours of searching on internet I found out how should I solve the problem. As it might be useful for others I offer solution.

This kind of problem has in Spring 3.1(which I use) different solution than in Spring 3.0(for which the mentioned tutorial was ment). Great article about the problem was presented here : [enter link description here](http://blog.42.nl/articles/leveraging-the-spring-mvc-3.1-handlermethodargumentresolver-interface)