# Spring OAuth (OAuth2): How can I get the client credentials in a Spring MVC controller?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, oauth-2.0, oauth-provider

In this snippet:

```
@RequestMapping(method = GET)
public List<Place> read(Principal principal) {
  principal.getName(); 
}
```

`principal.getName()` gives me the user identification but I need a way to receive the client credentials (client => the app who is using my API). How can I do this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I found a reasonable solution based on @luke-taylor answer.

```
@RequestMapping(method = GET)
public List<Place> read(OAuth2Authentication auth) {
  auth.getOAuth2Request().getClientId()
}
```

Comment: This returned me the Principal user and not the client id application

Comment: Updated version : `auth.getOAuth2Request().getClientId()`

Answer (score 24):

The client identity is available from the `Authentication` object which you can either cast the principal to, or get directly from the thread-local security context. Something like

```
Authentication a = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

String clientId = ((OAuth2Authentication) a).getAuthorizationRequest().getClientId();
```

If you don't want to put that code directly into your controller, you can implement a separate context accessor as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8765597/241990) and inject that into it instead.

Comment: nice answer, except the post date is little old. The spring boot 1.3.3 is using getOAuth2Request() instead of getAuthorizationRequest()

Comment: How about client secret?

Answer (score 5):

Fleshing out the `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` option a bit more.  In order to support the following:

```
@RequestMapping(
    value = WEB_HOOKS, 
    method = RequestMethod.GET, 
    produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public List<SomeDTO> getThoseDTOs(@CurrentClientId String clientId) 
{
    // Do something with clientId - it will be null if there was no authentication
}
```

We'll need the `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` registered with our Application Context (for me this was inside a `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`).  My `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` looks like this:

```
public class OAuth2ClientIdArgumentResolver implements HandlerMethodArgumentResolver {

    @Override
    public boolean supportsParameter(MethodParameter parameter) {
        return parameter.getParameterAnnotation(CurrentClientId.class) != null
                && parameter.getParameterType().equals(String.class);
    }

    @Override
    public Object resolveArgument(
            MethodParameter parameter,
            ModelAndViewContainer mavContainer, 
            NativeWebRequest webRequest,
            WebDataBinderFactory binderFactory) 
        throws Exception 
    {
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if(authentication == null) {
            return null;
        }
        String clientId = null;

        if (authentication.getClass().isAssignableFrom(OAuth2Authentication.class)) {
            clientId = ((OAuth2Authentication) authentication).getOAuth2Request().getClientId();
        }

        return clientId;
    }

}
```

And the `@interface` definition:

```
@Target({ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
public @interface CurrentClientId {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's also possible to obtain declaring a `org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.Jwt` object with `org.springframework.security.core.annotation.AuthenticationPrincipal` annotation.

```
@GetMapping
public String showClientId(@AuthenticationPrincipal Jwt principal) {
    return principal.getClaimAsString("clientId");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With the [deprecation of spring-oauth](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/wiki/OAuth-2.0-Migration-Guide) some of the other answers no longer work. I used the following to get the `clientId` in a `AuthenticationSuccessHandler` with spring-security 5:

```java
@Autowired
public OAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository oAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository

protected String getClientId(final Authentication authentication, HttpServletRequest request) {
    OAuth2AuthenticationToken auth = (OAuth2AuthenticationToken) authentication;
    OAuth2AuthorizedClient client = oAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository.loadAuthorizedClient(auth.getAuthorizedClientRegistrationId(), auth, request);
    String clientId = client.getClientRegistration().getClientId();
    return clientId;
}
```