# How to redirect to the homepage if the user accesses the login page after being logged in?

Tags: java, spring-security

Here is my spring security config:

```xml
<http pattern="/auth/login" security="none" />
<http pattern="/auth/loginFailed" security="none" />
<http pattern="/resources/**" security="none" />

<http auto-config="true" access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager">
    <intercept-url pattern="/auth/logout" access="permitAll"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="ADMINISTRATIVE_ACCESS"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="XYZ_ACCESS"/>

    <form-login
        login-page="/auth/login"
        authentication-failure-url="/auth/loginFailed"
        authentication-success-handler-ref="authenticationSuccessHandler" />
    <logout logout-url="/auth/logout" logout-success-url="/auth/login" />
</http>
```

The `authenticationSuccessHandler` extends the `SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler` ensuring that the user is redirected to the page he originally requested.

However, since `/auth/login` is marked as `security="none"`, I am unable to successfully redirect the user to the homepage if he accesses the login page after being logged in. I believe this is the right [user experience](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/26100/what-should-happen-if-the-login-page-is-accessed-post-login) too.

I tried the below too but the `Principal` object is always `null`, presumably because of the `security="none"` attribute again.

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/auth/login", method = GET)
public String showLoginForm(HttpServletRequest request, Principal principal) {
    if(principal != null) {
        return "redirect:/";
    }

    return "login";
}
```

Comment: One way I can think of is: `if(session.getAttribute("SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT") != null) return "redirect:/";` (_which actually works!_) But I am looking for a much neater approach.

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13131122/spring-security-redirect-if-already-logged-in

Comment: Please check this solution-->[Here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28257013/3287459

Answer (score 9):

I've checked the topic more deeply than last time and found that you have to determine if user is authenticated by yourself in controller. Row Winch (Spring Security dev) [says here](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?119015-Login-page-is-not-redirecting-for-logged-user):

> Spring Security is not aware of the internals of your application
>   (i.e. if you want to make your login page flex based upon if the user
>   is logged in or not). To show your home page when the login page is
>   requested and the user is logged in use the `SecurityContextHolder` in
>   the login page (or its controller) and redirect or forward the user to
>   the home page.

So solution would be determining if user requesting `/auth/login` is anonymous or not, something like below.

*applicationContext-security.xml*:

```xml
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true"
        access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager">
    <intercept-url pattern="/auth/login" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/auth/logout" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="ADMINISTRATIVE_ACCESS" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="XYZ_ACCESS" />

    <form-login login-page="/auth/login"
        authentication-failure-url="/auth/loginFailed"
        authentication-success-handler-ref="authenticationSuccessHandler" />
    <logout logout-url="/auth/logout" logout-success-url="/auth/login" />
</http>

<beans:bean id="defaultTargetUrl" class="java.lang.String">
    <beans:constructor-arg value="/content" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="authenticationTrustResolver"
        class="org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationTrustResolverImpl" />

<beans:bean id="authenticationSuccessHandler"
        class="com.example.spring.security.MyAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
    <beans:property name="defaultTargetUrl" ref="defaultTargetUrl" />
</beans:bean>
```

Add to *applicationContext.xml* bean definition:

```xml
<bean id="securityContextAccessor"
    class="com.example.spring.security.SecurityContextAccessorImpl" />
```

which is class

```
public final class SecurityContextAccessorImpl
      implements SecurityContextAccessor {

  @Autowired
  private AuthenticationTrustResolver authenticationTrustResolver;

  @Override
  public boolean isCurrentAuthenticationAnonymous() {
    final Authentication authentication =
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    return authenticationTrustResolver.isAnonymous(authentication);
  }
}
```

implementing simple interface

```
public interface SecurityContextAccessor {
  boolean isCurrentAuthenticationAnonymous();
}
```

([`SecurityContextHolder` accessing code is decoupled from controller, I followed suggestion from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8765597/708434), hence `SecurityContextAccessor` interface.)

And last but not least redirect logic in controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/auth")
public class AuthController {
  @Autowired
  SecurityContextAccessor securityContextAccessor;

  @Autowired
  @Qualifier("defaultTargetUrl")
  private String defaultTargetUrl;

  @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public String login() {
    if (securityContextAccessor.isCurrentAuthenticationAnonymous()) {
      return "login";
    } else {
      return "redirect:" + defaultTargetUrl;
    }
  }
}
```

Defining `defaultTargetUrl` String bean seems like a hack, but I don't have better way not to hardcode url... (Actually in our project we use [`<util:constant>`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#xsd-config-body-schemas-util-constant) with class containing static final String fields.) But it works after all.

Comment: if i am using spring useretailsService to authenticate users, how to check in code if user is authenticated and not anonymous ?

Comment: @MahmoudSaleh userDetailsService has nothing to do with this apprach, as long you put authentication object into SecurityContext it should work. If it doesn't work, ask separate question and provide your configuration.

Answer (score 7):

You could also restrict your login page to `ROLE_ANONYMOUS` and set an `<access-denied-handler />`:

```
<access-denied-handler ref="accessDeniedHandler" />
<intercept-url pattern="/auth/login" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS" />
```

And in your handler check if the user is already authenticated:

```
@Service
public class AccessDeniedHandler extends AccessDeniedHandlerImpl {
    private final String HOME_PAGE = "/index.html";

    @Override
    public void handle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AccessDeniedException e) throws IOException, ServletException {
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if (auth != null && !(auth instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken)) {
            response.sendRedirect(HOME_PAGE);
        }

        super.handle(request, response, e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Implement a Redirect Interceptor for this purpose:

The Interceptor (implementing [`HandlerInterceptor`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerInterceptor.html) interface) check if someone try to access the login page, and if this person is already logged in, then the interceptor sends a redirect to the index page.

```
public class LoginPageRedirectInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {    

    private String[] loginPagePrefixes = new String[] { "/login" };

    private String redirectUrl = "/index.html";

    private UrlPathHelper urlPathHelper = new UrlPathHelper();

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
                             HttpServletResponse response,
                             Object handler) throws Exception {

        if (isInLoginPaths(this.urlPathHelper.getLookupPathForRequest(request))
                           && isAuthenticated()) {
            response.setContentType("text/plain");
            sendRedirect(request, response);
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    private boolean isAuthenticated() {
        Authentication authentication =
                        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if (authentication == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (authentication instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken) {
            return false;
        }
        return authentication.isAuthenticated();
    }

    private void sendRedirect(HttpServletRequest request,
                              HttpServletResponse response) {

        String encodedRedirectURL = response.encodeRedirectURL(
                                 request.getContextPath() + this.redirectUrl);
        response.setStatus(HttpStatus.SC_TEMPORARY_REDIRECT);
        response.setHeader("Location", encodedRedirectURL);
    }

    private boolean isInLoginPaths(final String requestUrl) {   
        for (String login : this.loginPagePrefixes) {
            if (requestUrl.startsWith(login)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where to define this interceptor

Comment: @Viswanath L: with in the config xml interceptor tag: http://spring.io/blog/2009/12/21/mvc-simplifications-in-spring-3-0/

Answer (score 0):

You can keep it simple flow by `access-denied-page` attribute in `http` element or as [dtrunk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1163457/dtrunk) said to write handler for access denied as well as. the config would be like

```
<http access-denied-page="/403" ... >
 <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS" />
 <intercept-url pattern="/user/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
 <intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
 <form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/home" ... />
 ...
</http>
```

in controller for `/403`

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/403", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String accessDenied() { //simple impl
    return "redirect:/home";
}
```

and for `/home`

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/home", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String home(Authentication authentication) {
 // map as many home urls with Role
    Map<String, String> dashBoardUrls = new HashMap<String, String>();
    dashBoardUrls.put("ROLE_USER", "/user/dashboard");
    dashBoardUrls.put("ROLE_ADMIN", "/admin/dashboard");

    String url = null;

    Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> grants = authentication
            .getAuthorities();
 // for one role per user
    for (GrantedAuthority grantedAuthority : grants) {
        url = dashBoardUrls.get(grantedAuthority.getAuthority());
    }
    if (url == null)
        return "/errors/default_access_denied.jsp";

    return "redirect:" + url;
}
```

and when you make request for `/admin/dashboard` without logged in, it will redirect `/login` automatically by security

Answer (score 0):

```
<http pattern="/login" auto-config="true" disable-url-rewriting="true">
  <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS"/>
  <access-denied-handler error-page="/index.jsp"/>
</http>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try checking

```
if(SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null)
```

True means the user isn't authenticated, and thus can be sent to the login page. I don't know how robust/reliable this is, but it seems reasonable to try.

Comment: A down vote without a comment is cowardice and betrays your own lack of knowledge.