# Deny log in with already authenticated session

Tags: java, spring-security

How can I deny a second log in (with same or different user) to a already authenticated HTTP session?

For [Form-Login](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.8.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#nsa-form-login) I found following work-arounds:

- [Redirect in Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13132645/5277820)
- [Redirect in View](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12640004/5277820)
- [Restrict the login page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27924524/5277820)

But these work-arounds are not perfect, because I can still access the  `login-processing-url` and execute a second log in. That is a problem for all authentication mechanisms without a login page, like [HTTP Basic Authentication](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.8.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#nsa-http-basic) and [Kerberos](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-kerberos/).

My Java Configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public static class MyWebSecurityConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/**").hasAuthority("ROLE_user")
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginProcessingUrl("/Login").permitAll()
                .loginPage("/index.jsp").permitAll()
                .defaultSuccessUrl("start.jsp")
                .failureUrl("/index.jsp")
                .and()
            .httpBasic();
    }
}
```

Example:

1. User A: Logs in with HTTP Basic Authentication.
2. System: Creates a session and returns a session cookie.
3. User B: Logs in with HTTP Basic Authentication on same machine and sends session cookie.
4. System: Creates a new session, merges all values from old session into new session (see [SessionFixationProtectionStrategy](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.2.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/session/SessionFixationProtectionStrategy.html#setMigrateSessionAttributes(boolean))), destroys old session and returns new session cookie.

Comment: Implement custom `SessionAuthenticationStrategy`.

Comment: @Aleksandr M: Thank you. Maybe I could check, if the session is already authenticated and throw an exception. But at the moment I'm not sure that the `SessionAuthenticationStrategy` is executed before `BASIC_AUTH_FILTER` in filter chaein. I will read the Spring Security Reference and try to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

put following entry in web.xml

```
<listener>
  <listener-class>org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
</listener>
```

and in your spring security config, use the following snippet:

```
<http>
  <session-management>
    <concurrency-control max-sessions="1" expired-url="/redirect-page" />
  </session-management>
</http>
```

Comment: Your solution has two disadvantages: 1. The user cannot log in twice with seperated sessions. 2. It works only for the same user, a different user can still use the same session. I will update my question, to make it clear.

Comment: M. Deinum: Sure, I'm authenticated after log in, but with another user. That's the problem. I don't want to share a session (or merge) with to users.