# Spring Security Login Issue after re-login ... in same session

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have done Login and logout in my application by Spring Security

**Situation:**

After logging in with valid credentials I am directing role based page. Than after clicking back button it is taking me to login screen. Again if I give valid credentials, it is not redirecting to role based page, it staying login page only .

And Still the session is there its not invalidating ..

if I enter valid url in browser its showing valid page with previous logged details ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> roleList = SecurityContextHolder
        .getContext().getAuthentication().getAuthorities();
```

Use this in your sign-in method and check if user has roles(ROLE_USER or ROLE_ADMIN) that is defined by you in spring-security file. Then use:

```
ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();

if (roleList.contains(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"))){

    return mav.setViewName("redirect:/homepageafterlogin");

//it will automatically redirect to homepage if you hit the login url or     
//press back button.

} else {
    if (roleList.contains(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ANONYMOUS"))){

        //means user is already not logged in then 
        return mav.setViewName("/signin.jsp");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## account#deleted#PostedBelowByOtherAccount