# Redirect to home page if session is active

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

How to redirect a user to the homepage if an already authenticated user accesses the login page?

Here is config:

```
<sec:http authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManagerAlias">
    <sec:form-login login-page="/login.do" always-use-default-target="false" default-target-url="/interceptor.do" authentication-failure-url="/login.do?code=auth" />
    <sec:access-denied-handler ref="accessDeniedHandler"/>
    <sec:session-management session-authentication-error-url="/login.do" invalid-session-url="/login.do"> </sec:session-management>
    <sec:logout invalidate-session="true" logout-success-url="/login.do"/>  
</sec:http>
```

Comment: I didn't understand what you really want to do. If i rephrase, you want to redirect the user to the home page after a login?

Comment: guys I simply want if user is already logged in and then he try to open login page again than he simple redirects to home page, he cannot able to access login page again until he logsout

Comment: Duplicate of [How to redirect to the homepage if the user accesses the login page after being logged in?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12597519)