# How to validate Controller method argument in Spring with JSR validations?

Tags: java, spring, validation, controller, arguments

I am validating my form field with given piece of code.

```
//controller method
public String addBusiness(@Valid @ModelAttribute("myForm") MyForm myForm, ...)
{
   //logic will go here.
}

//form 
@Component
public class MyForm{
    @Pattern(regexp = "[0-9]{3,10}", message = "should be valid number")
    public String getZip_code()
    {
       return this.zip_code;
    }
}
```

Now I want same validation on `zip_code` in another method of controller like,

```
@RequestMapping(value = "${validation.url}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public List<String> getCityList(@RequestParam(value = "zip_code", required = true) final String zip_code)
{
    //logic goes here
}
```

How is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not. `@Valid` doesn't apply to `@RequestParam` annotated parameters. You can create a custom `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` to do this or do the validation yourself in the method.

Comment: Hi @SotiriosDelimanolis Thanks, can you give me any example of `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` for such validation, if possible?

Comment: @VishalZanzrukia It's just an interface you implement and register. The implementation is use-case dependent. Google the class and you'll find examples like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17331448/spring-handlermethodargumentresolver-not-executing).