# Distinguish empty value from empty string ("") in Url query parameter

Tags: java, http, url, spring-mvc, httprequest

How to distinguish URL without value like this `/url?var` from `/url?var=""` in Spring MVC?

Method `HttpServletRequest::getParameterMap()` in controller returns `""` in both ways.

I need this to separate commands from queries to specified resource.

Answer (score 3):

One simple way of going about doing what you want to is use the `getQueryString()` of `HttpServletRequest`. You would just check and see if the returned String contains the pattern you are looking for.

If you need something like that often (as in many controller methods) you could also easily create a custom `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` that will indicate the presence of a String in the URL.

[Here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/method/support/HandlerMethodArgumentResolver.html) is the relevant Javadoc and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17331448/spring-handlermethodargumentresolver-not-executing) is an example

Answer (score 0):

/url?var is a valid URL which states that you have a parameter **var** which is not initialized.

So by default it is initialized to empty string. That's the framework behavior.

If you don't want to see that parameter coming in HttpServletRequest::getParameterMap(), just don't use it with URL (i.e. /url should be your call)

Comment: That wouldn't solve my problem. I'm looking for method, that would for example return map of parameters and those parameter like ```/url?car``` would return ```null``` - ```/url?query=asd&run -> ["query":"asd", "run":null]``` .