# Injecting Custom Principal to Controllers by Spring Security

Tags: spring, spring-security

servletApi() support of Spring Security is great.

I want to inject custom Principal as this:

```
public interface UserPrincipal extends Principal {
   public Integer getId();
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/")
public ResponseEntity<List<Conversation>> listAfter(UserPrincipal user){
   // implementation
}  

or


@RequestMapping(value = "/")
public ResponseEntity<List<Conversation>> listAfter(UserPrincipalImpl user){
   // implementation
}
```

Spring has support for injecting `Principal` instances with the help of `ServletRequestMethodArgumentResolver`.

It is injecting principal as this:

```
else if (Principal.class.isAssignableFrom(paramType)) {
    return request.getUserPrincipal();
}
```

Here is the place where the problem begins. `request` is here an instance of `SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper`. It has an implementation of:

```
@Override
public Principal getUserPrincipal() {
    Authentication auth = getAuthentication();

    if ((auth == null) || (auth.getPrincipal() == null)) {
        return null;
    }

    return auth;
 }
```

Because an `Authentication` is also an `Principal`. (The only part of spring security I did not like so far. I will ask this a separate question as well.)

This is causing a problem. Because `Authentication` is a `Principal` not a `UserPrincipal`.

How can I resolve this problem? Do I need to implement an authentication which is a UserPrincipal as well? Or should I change HandlerMethodArgumentResolver order a create a custom resolver? (This is not easy for Spring MVC because internal handlers has higher priority.)

As a extra information:

I am using Spring Security M2 and my configuration for `AuthenticationManagerBuilder` is simply:

```
@Override
protected void registerAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception        {

  auth
     .userDetailsService(detailsService);
}
```

Any help?

Comment: Does this help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8764545/best-practice-for-getting-active-users-userdetails/8769670#8769670 -- is a slightly different question, but I think in the end you try to solve the same problem.

Comment: Thanks @Ralph but it could not help me. My situation is little different than that question. There are major differences and also did not like explicit casting of Authentication which means that my modules also must be depend on Spring Security.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Fundamentally this seems like trouble integrating with Spring MVC and not a Spring Security issue. Spring Security has no way of knowing that Authentication@getPrinicpal() implements Principal since the API returns an Object.

I see a few options for you. Each has some pros and cons, but I think the best is using `@ModelAttribute` and `@ControllerAdvice`

## `@ModelAttribute` and `@ControllerAdvice`

The easiest option is annotate a method with `@ModelAttribute` on custom `@ControllerAdvice`. You can find details in [the Spring Reference](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-modelattrib-methods).

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class SecurityControllerAdvice {

    @ModelAttribute
    public UserPrincipal customPrincipal(Authentication a) {
        return (UserPrincipal) a == null ? null : a.getPrincipal();
    }
}
```

Now in your controller you can do something like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/")
public ResponseEntity<List<Conversation>> listAfter(@ModelAttribute UserPrincipal user){
   // implementation
}
```

Note that the `@ModelAttribute` is necessary only to ensure the `@ModelAttribute` is used over the HttpServletRequest#getPrincipal(). If it did not implement Principal, `@ModelAttribute` is not required.

## `@Value` and ExpressionValueMethodArgumentResolver

You can also do something like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/")
public ResponseEntity<List<Conversation>> listAfter(
  @Value("#{request.userPrincipal.principal}") UserPrincipal user){
   // implementation
}
```

This works because the HttpServletRequest is available as an attribute to the ExpressionValueMethodArgumentResolver (added by default by Spring MVC) which allows accessing things via [SpEL](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html). I find this less attractive than `@ModelAttribute` due to the constant that must be in the `@Value` annotation. It will be nicer when [SPR-10760](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-10760) is resolved which would allow for your own custom annotation to be used like:

```
@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Value("#{request.userPrincipal.principal}")
public @interface CurrentUser { }
```

## @Autowire RequestMappingHandlerAdapter

This is a bit sloppy because the RequestMappingHandlerAdapter has already been initialized, but you can change the ordering of the HandlerMethodArgumentResolvers as shown here:

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfiguration 
  extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    ...
    @Autowired
    public void setArgumentResolvers(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter adapter) {
        List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> resolvers = new ArrayList<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver>();
        resolvers.add(new CustomPrincipalArgumentResolver());
        resolvers.addAll(adapter.getArgumentResolvers().getResolvers());
        adapter.setArgumentResolvers(resolvers);
    }
}
```

## Subclass WebMvcConfigurationSupport

You can also extend WebMvcConfigurationSupport instead of using `@EnableWebMvc` to ensure your HandlerMethodArgumentResolver is used first. For example:

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {
    ...

    @Bean
    @Override
    public RequestMappingHandlerAdapter requestMappingHandlerAdapter() {
        RequestMappingHandlerAdapter adapter = super.requestMappingHandlerAdapter()();
        List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> resolvers = new ArrayList<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver>();
        resolvers.add(new CustomPrincipalArgumentResolver());
        resolvers.addAll(adapter.getArgumentResolvers().getResolvers());
        adapter.setArgumentResolvers(resolvers);
        return adapter;
    }
}
```

Comment: Rob, thank you so much. You really taught me many things. :) Today I had already implemented a custom method argument handler. And in order to change order of handlers, I had to use reflection :) Your implementation is better than mine. Thanks

Answer (score 17):

I know this is an old question, but as it does come up on top on Google when searching for injecting a Principal, I'll post a 2020 update:

Since Spring Security 4.0 you can just simply inject an `@AuthenticationPrincipal` into your controller methods:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/")
public ResponseEntity<List<Conversation>> listAfter(@AuthenticationPrincipal UserPrincipal user){
   // implementation
}
```

This will work out of the box, no additional config required.

Comment: Good point. Incidentally, it was @Rob Winch, who implemented `@AuthenticationPrincipal`/`AuthenticationPrincipalArgumentResolver` :)

Comment: Can you inject the principal into service methods?