# Inject custom OidcUser wrapper with @AuthenticationPrincipal

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, okta

I'm using springboot security with Okta for authentication. I'm currently trying to create an abstract class implementing OidcUser to encapsulate some methods. For instance:

```
public abstract class OktaUser implements OidcUser {

    public UUID getUserId() {
        return UUID.fromString(Objects.requireNonNull(this.getAttribute("user_id")));
    }
}
```

I normaly inject OidcUser (Working)

```
@GetMapping
public User currentUser(@AuthenticationPrincipal OidcUser oidcUser) {
    UUID id = UUID.fromString(Objects.requireNonNull(oidcUser.getAttribute("user_id")));

    return userService.getUser(id);
}
```

But I want to do it like this (Not working)

```
@GetMapping
public User currentUser(@AuthenticationPrincipal OktaUser oktaUser) {
    return userService.getUser(oktaUser.getMicaUserId());
}
```

However, `oktaUser` is always null. Is there a way to register `OktaUser` as `AuthenticationPrincipal`?

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a solution from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17741787/injecting-custom-principal-to-controllers-by-spring-security)

With the ControllerAdvice, I was able to build and return my custom OidcUser.

```
@ModelAttribute
public OktaUser oktaUser(@AuthenticationPrincipal OidcUser oidcUser) {
    return oidcUser == null
        ? null
        : new OktaUser(oidcUser.getAuthorities(), oidcUser.getIdToken(), oidcUser.getUserInfo());
}
```

And i can inject it like that

```
@GetMapping
public void getAll(@ModelAttribute OktaUser oktaUser) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Spring Security guide:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.2.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-authentication-principal

It walks through exactly this. You can even define your annotation like `@MicaUser` which would resolve your custom implementation.

Comment: I was not able to inject my custom type even by going through the guide. I solved my problem with the post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17741787/injecting-custom-principal-to-controllers-by-spring-security.
Maybe it's because of the OidsUser?