# Auth0 and SpringBoot securing an API with null for AuthenticationPrincipal OidcUser

Tags: java, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, openid-connect, auth0

I want to secure a backend API written in Java/SpringBoot and using Auth0.   I am following the [Auth0 example](https://auth0.com/blog/spring-boot-authorization-tutorial-secure-an-api-java/).

Everything works fine and as expected, however, when I apply this to my application I want to detect the user who made the API call.  In various examples I've come across it appears to be possible with Spring Security by injecting the OidcUser.

Some relevant links I've found are:

1. [Inject custom OidcUser wrapper with @AuthenticationPrincipal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60553023/inject-custom-oidcuser-wrapper-with-authenticationprincipal)
2. [Spring Security and OIDC connect](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-openid-connect)

In my application, my controller looks like this:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", maxAge = 3600)
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/project")
public class ProjectController {

    @PostMapping("/add")
    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('write:project')")
    public ResponseEntity<DummySubmitResponseDto> createNewProject(@AuthenticationPrincipal OidcUser oidcUser,
                                                                   @RequestBody DummyDto dummyDto) {

        DummySubmitResponseDto projectSubmitResponseDto = new DummySubmitResponseDto("TheResponse");
        return new ResponseEntity<>(projectSubmitResponseDto, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
}
```

I'm using a React SPA to get an access-token.  I save it manually and use Curl or POSTMAN to call the API.  However, oidcUser is always null.

I'm not sure if I'm following the correct approach.  Separate to this, I don't understand how the Backend (which is a resource server) is able to get the user information from the access token.

Comment: I realised I can call Object user = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal(); inside the method but I'd like to understand the above code better.

Comment: Wich token are you using when calling backend from the frontend ? Id_token or access_token ?

Comment: You should use the access token. The id_token is only for the front end

Comment: We have a problem because we are getting opaque access tokens from auth0. When the backend is called they don't have a payload inside.

Comment: Not sure how to solve your problem. My front end is React and I followed the guidance from the Auth0 SPA document.