# AuthenticationPrincipal is empty when using EnableWebSecurity

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

As of [Spring Security doc: 34.1 @EnableWebMvcSecurity](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-enablewebmvcsecurity) states, the `@EnableWebMvcSecurity` was replaced by `@EnableWebSecurity`.

But when I try to get the `UserDetails` in controller by the `@AuthenticationPrincipal`, I got a empty object: the username is `""`.   I also tried the `@EnableWebMvcSecurity`, but unfortunately the `UserDetails` is `null`.

But I can get the `UserDetails` by the traditional way, like this:

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
```

My question is, what the correct way to get my custom `UserDetails` (`Account`) when I use `@EnableWebSecurity`?

Below are the related source code:

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
@Secured("ROLE_USER")
public String postRoom(@Valid @ModelAttribute Room room, BindingResult result, Model model, @AuthenticationPrincipal Account principal) {
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return "room_form";
    }

    Account account = accountRepository.findByUsername(principal.getUsername());
    room.setAccountId(account.getId());
    room.setLastModified(new Date());
    roomRepository.save(room);
    return "room_list";
}
```

Security configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    private SecurityProperties security;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll()
            .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/login?error").permitAll()
            .and().logout().permitAll()
            .and().rememberMe()
            .and().csrf().disable();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(this.dataSource).passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder(8));
    }
}
```

And the `Account.java`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class Account implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String username;
    private String password;
    private boolean enabled;

    @Lob
    private byte[] avatar;

// getter / setter ...
}
```

Comment: Add your security configuration as well perhaps. Is `Account` the object that is used to authenticate through `UserDetailsService`? Also give a try with `Principal` object instead of `Account` to see if that has any result.

Comment: Hi Jim, I have a similar issue. Have you found the reason why you got the `Principal` through the context but not when using the `@AuthenticationPrincipal` annotation ?

Comment: No. Please try the traditional way.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in one of the comments on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8764545/how-to-get-active-users-userdetails/8769670#8769670), the Account class you're returning needs to be assignable from `authentication.getPrincipal()` which means your Account class most likely needs to implement the `UserDetails` interface (as a minimum) since the `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User` class does. Look at Java's API doc for `UserDetails` or this [page](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-authentication-principal) for a feel.

If you change the type after @AuthenticationPrincipal to `User`, the null problem will probably go away.

Depending on how you setup your database, having the Account class implement `UserDetails` might introduce too much logic into Account since it's supposed to be a model.

Since you're using `@EnableWebSecurity`, you don't need to configure a custom `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` as some posts suggest.

### My personal suggestion

Note I'm using Spring Boot

Since using jdbcAuthentication requires you to setup your database in a pre-defined way (and most likely the schema you had in mind is nothing like the one they created), your best bet is to create a custom schema and configure your own user authentication service (it's not hard). Personally, I configured a custom user authentication service in the `configureGlobal...` method. One liner.

```
auth.userDetailsService(userService).passwordEncoder...
```

where my custom userService implements the `UserDetailsService` interface which only provides one method for you to implement `public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username)` Spring Security will call that method to authenticate users. Within that `loadUserByUsername` method, I retrieved my user info from the database, created a new `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User` object, stuffed username, password, and permissions into the User object and returned it.
I have the following at the end of my method.

```
return new User(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), permissions);
```

Because I returned `User` which implements `UserDetails` interface, `@AuthenticationPrincipal User user` will work for me.

DO NOTE that `permissions` variable needs to be a class which implements the `GrantedAuthority` interface, or a collection of that type. That interface also has only one method for you to implement `public String getAuthority()`, which basically can return any string you like (presumably the names of permission / roles in your database).

I'll assume you know how Spring Security deals with authorization. It's saddening that Spring Security uses solely Role-based authorization (if I'm wrong I'd be happy to be corrected), instead of group + permission for a more granular control. You can, however, work around that by creating a `groups` table and a `rights` table in your database and having a corresponding classes implement GrantedAuthority interface. You'll effectively be separating "roles" into those two categories.

If you are really keen on using your own class via `@AuthenticationPrincipal`, or if you want more than username and password
I would probably create a wrapper class around your Account class (to take logic out of Account) and have the wrapper class implement `UserDetails`  I've done this successfully.

Lastly, I would highly recommend adding a service layer on top of your repository layer, and get your controllers to talk to the service layer. This setup adds a layer of security (since hackers will have to hack your service layer as well before reaching your repository layer) and also takes the logic out the repository layer since it should only be used for CRUD, nothing more.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tried it, but this should work for you:

```
@Configuration
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationPrincipalArgumentResolver authenticationPrincipalArgumentResolver(){
        return new AuthenticationPrincipalArgumentResolver();
    }

    @Override
    public void addArgumentResolvers(List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> argumentResolvers) {
        argumentResolvers.add(authenticationPrincipalArgumentResolver());
    }
}
```

Comment: from where "requestEntityMethodArgumentResolver" this variable came?

Comment: @VijayShegokar I would just delete that bit. Don't know where Jannik got it from but with Spring 5.1.13, it was unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

> AuthenticationPrincipal is empty.
>   But I can get the UserDetails by the traditional way, like this:
>
> ```
> SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
> ```

Configuring of `argument-resolvers` helped for me

```
<mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:argument-resolvers>
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.web.method.annotation.AuthenticationPrincipalArgumentResolver"/>
    </mvc:argument-resolvers>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

Also you can see [34.2 @AuthenticationPrincipal](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-authentication-principal) section

> Once AuthenticationPrincipalArgumentResolver is properly configured, you can be entirely decoupled from Spring Security in your Spring MVC layer.

How i understand this mean you should add argument resolver manually. Or

> By using Section 34.1, “@EnableWebMvcSecurity” you will automatically have this added to your Spring MVC configuration

Also [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8764545/how-to-get-active-users-userdetails)

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem. I had to make my own `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` and annotation.
The following code have been tested and works

First create the annotation

```
@Target({ ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface CurrentUser{}
```

And a simple config

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "x.x.x")
public class ApplicationConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

    @Override
    public void addArgumentResolvers(List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> argumentResolvers) {
        argumentResolvers.add(new HandlerMethodArgumentResolver() {

            public boolean supportsParameter(MethodParameter parameter) {
                return findMethodAnnotation(CurrentUser.class, parameter) != null;
            }

            public Object resolveArgument(
                    MethodParameter parameter,
                    ModelAndViewContainer mavContainer,
                    NativeWebRequest webRequest,
                    WebDataBinderFactory binderFactory) throws Exception
            {
                Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
                Object principal = authentication.getPrincipal();

                if(principal != null && !parameter.getParameterType().isAssignableFrom(principal.getClass()))
                    throw new ClassCastException(principal + " is not assignable to " + parameter.getParameterType());

                return principal;
            }

            <T extends Annotation> T findMethodAnnotation(Class<T> annotationClass, MethodParameter parameter) {
                T annotation = parameter.getParameterAnnotation(annotationClass);
                if(annotation != null) {
                    return annotation;
                }
                Annotation[] annotationsToSearch = parameter.getParameterAnnotations();
                for(Annotation toSearch : annotationsToSearch) {
                    annotation = AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(toSearch.annotationType(), annotationClass);
                    if(annotation != null) {
                        return annotation;
                    }
                }
                return null;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And then use it in a controller

```
@RequestMapping("/userget")
public User message(@CurrentUser User user){
    return user;
}
```

Note that `User` does not require to extends `UserDetails` anyamore.
Hope this (will) help(s)