# Null @AuthenticationPrincipal with Spring-Boot / Security

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot, spring-web

I setup my Spring Security application according to the [reference document](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/) and after hours of troubleshooting I continue to get a null **@AuthenticationPrincipal** passed into my controller.

The authentication mechanism is working fine against the users in my database but still a null @AuthenticationPrincipal. I consulted several internet posts including [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29657039/authenticationprincipal-is-empty-when-using-enablewebsecurity), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8764545/how-to-get-active-users-userdetails) but still I am getting null.

I am using Spring-Boot 1.2.2 and Spring Security 3.2.6.

**Relevant POM:**

```
<parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.2.RELEASE</version>
  <relativePath/>
</parent>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

**Application:**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class AuditWebApplication {
  // code
}
```

**WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter:**

```
@Configuration
@Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled=true)
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .httpBasic()
            .and()
            .logout()
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/#/login")
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/index.html", "/views/**", // public side.
                        "/images/**", "/scripts/**", "/styles/**", "/vendor/**", "/")
            .permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated().and().csrf()
            .csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository()).and()
            .addFilterAfter(csrfHeaderFilter(), SessionManagementFilter.class);
    }
```

**UserDetailsService:**

```
@Transactional
@Service
public class UserServiceBean implements UserService {
  @Override
  public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    // Custom domain User object, not spring security
    User user = userRepository.findByusername(username);
    if(user == null) {
      throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Unable to load user by username = '" + username + "'");
    }
    List<UserRole> userRoles = userRoleRepository.findAllByUserId(user.getId());
    user.setUserRoles(userRoles);
    return new UserRepositoryUserDetails(user);
  }

  // User here refers to my application's domain User object, not Spring Security
  private final static class UserRepositoryUserDetails extends User implements UserDetails {

    public UserRepositoryUserDetails(User user) {
      super(user);
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
      List<String> authoritiesList = new ArrayList<String>();
      List<UserRole> userRoles = getUserRoles();
      userRoles.forEach((ur) -> {
        if(ur.isActive()) {
          authoritiesList.add(ur.getRoleDesc());
        }
      });

      String authoritiesString = StringUtils.join(authoritiesList, ',');
      return AuthorityUtils.commaSeparatedStringToAuthorityList(authoritiesString);
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
      return getLdapUID();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
      return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
      return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
      return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
      return isActive() ;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        // fake for now
      return "password";
    }

  }

}

public interface UserService extends UserDetailsService {
  // signatures
}
```

**Controller:**

```
import org.springframework.security.web.bind.annotation.AuthenticationPrincipal;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;

@RequestMapping(value="/products", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<Map<String,Object>> products(@AuthenticationPrincipal User user){
  // user is null
}
```

**Relevant Maven Dependency Tree:**

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Web Project 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.9:tree (default-cli) @ web-build ---
[WARNING] Using Maven 2 dependency tree to get verbose output, which may be inconsistent with actual Maven 3 resolution
[INFO] com.company:web-build:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- com.company:common-build:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:jar:1.2.2.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- (org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:jar:1.2.2.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- com.company:data-build:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- (com.company:common-build:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:jar:1.2.2.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:jar:1.2.2.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:jar:1.2.2.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.4.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- (org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.3.2:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jetty:jar:1.2.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-jsp:jar:9.2.9.v20150224:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.eclipse.jetty.toolchain:jetty-schemas:jar:3.1.M0:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- javax.servlet.jsp:javax.servlet.jsp-api:jar:2.3.1:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.glassfish.web:javax.servlet.jsp:jar:2.3.2:compile
[INFO] |     |  |  +- (org.glassfish:javax.el:jar:3.0.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     |  |  \- (javax.servlet.jsp:javax.servlet.jsp-api:jar:2.3.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     |  +- org.eclipse.jetty.orbit:javax.servlet.jsp.jstl:jar:1.2.0.v201105211821:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.glassfish.web:javax.servlet.jsp.jstl:jar:1.2.2:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.glassfish:javax.el:jar:3.0.0:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- org.eclipse.jetty.orbit:org.eclipse.jdt.core:jar:3.8.2.v20130121:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-webapp:jar:9.2.9.v20150224:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-xml:jar:9.2.9.v20150224:compile
[INFO] |     |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:jar:9.2.9.v20150224:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlet:jar:9.2.9.v20150224:compile
[INFO] |     |     \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-security:jar:9.2.9.v20150224:compile
[INFO] |     |        \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:jar:9.2.9.v20150224:compile
[INFO] |     |           +- (javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.1.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     |           +- (org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http:jar:9.2.9.v20150224:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     |           \- (org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:jar:9.2.9.v20150224:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     +- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-server:jar:9.2.9.v20150224:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-common:jar:9.2.9.v20150224:compile
[INFO] |     |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-api:jar:9.2.9.v20150224:compile
[INFO] |     |  |  +- (org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:jar:9.2.9.v20150224:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:jar:9.2.9.v20150224:compile
[INFO] |     |  |     \- (org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:jar:9.2.9.v20150224:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     |  +- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-client:jar:9.2.9.v20150224:compile
[INFO] |     |  |  +- (org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:jar:9.2.9.v20150224:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     |  |  +- (org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:jar:9.2.9.v20150224:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     |  |  \- (org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-common:jar:9.2.9.v20150224:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     |  +- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-servlet:jar:9.2.9.v20150224:compile
[INFO] |     |  |  +- (org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-api:jar:9.2.9.v20150224:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     |  |  \- (javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.1.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     |  +- (org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlet:jar:9.2.9.v20150224:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http:jar:9.2.9.v20150224:compile
[INFO] |     |     \- (org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:jar:9.2.9.v20150224:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     \- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:javax-websocket-server-impl:jar:9.2.9.v20150224:compile
[INFO] |        +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-annotations:jar:9.2.9.v20150224:compile
[INFO] |        |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-plus:jar:9.2.9.v20150224:compile
[INFO] |        |  |  +- (org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-webapp:jar:9.2.9.v20150224:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |        |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-jndi:jar:9.2.9.v20150224:compile
[INFO] |        |  |     \- (org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:jar:9.2.9.v20150224:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |        |  +- (org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-webapp:jar:9.2.9.v20150224:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |        |  +- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |        |  +- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.0.1:compile
[INFO] |        |  \- org.ow2.asm:asm-commons:jar:5.0.1:compile
[INFO] |        |     \- org.ow2.asm:asm-tree:jar:5.0.1:compile
[INFO] |        |        \- (org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.0.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |        +- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:javax-websocket-client-impl:jar:9.2.9.v20150224:compile
[INFO] |        |  +- (org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-client:jar:9.2.9.v20150224:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |        |  \- (javax.websocket:javax.websocket-api:jar:1.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |        +- (org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-server:jar:9.2.9.v20150224:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |        \- javax.websocket:javax.websocket-api:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:jar:1.2.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:1.2.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:1.2.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.1.5.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 3.2.8.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.1.5.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 3.2.8.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:1.2.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:1.2.2.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.14:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:1.2.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.10:compile (version managed from 1.7.6)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.10:compile - version managed from 1.7.6; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.10:compile - version managed from 1.7.6; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.10:compile - version managed from 1.7.6; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.1.5.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 3.2.8.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.14:compile - scope updated from runtime; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.1.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.1.5.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 3.2.8.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.1.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.1.5.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 3.2.8.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.1.5.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 3.2.8.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.1.5.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 3.2.8.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.1.5.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 3.2.8.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.1.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.1.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.1.5.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 3.2.8.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.1.5.RELEASE:compile (version managed from 3.2.8.RELEASE)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.1.5.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 3.2.8.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.1.5.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 3.2.8.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.1.5.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 3.2.8.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.1.5.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 3.2.8.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:3.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:3.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.1.5.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 3.2.8.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.1.5.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 3.2.8.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.1.5.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 3.2.8.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.1.5.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 3.2.8.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.1.5.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 3.2.8.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.1.5.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 3.2.8.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.1.5.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 3.2.8.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.1.5.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 3.2.8.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.1.5.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 3.2.8.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:3.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:3.2.6.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.1.5.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 3.2.8.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.1.5.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 3.2.8.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.1.5.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 3.2.8.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.1.5.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 3.2.8.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.1.5.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 3.2.8.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.1.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     +- (aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.1.5.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 3.2.8.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.1.5.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 3.2.8.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:1.2.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:1.2.2.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:1.2.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:8.0.20:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:8.0.20:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-logging-juli:jar:8.0.20:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:8.0.20:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- (org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:8.0.20:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.4.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.4.5:compile - version managed from 2.4.0; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.4.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.1.3.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.1.3.GA:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.1.5.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 3.2.8.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.1.5.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 3.2.8.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.1.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.1.5.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 3.2.8.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     +- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.1.5.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 3.2.8.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.1.5.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 3.2.8.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     +- (org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.1.5.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 3.2.8.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     \- (org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.1.5.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 3.2.8.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:jar:1.2.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:1.2.2.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.1.5.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 3.2.8.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.1.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.1.5.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 3.2.8.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.1.5.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 3.2.8.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.1.5.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc:jar:8.0.20:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-juli:jar:8.0.20:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.1.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.1.5.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 3.2.8.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.1.5.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 3.2.8.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:jar:1.2.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:1.2.2.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.1.5.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 3.2.8.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.1.5.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 3.2.8.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.8.5:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.8.5:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.3.2:compile
[INFO] +- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:1.2.2.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- junit:junit:jar:4.12:test
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test - version managed from 1.1; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:1.10.19:test
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test - version managed from 1.1; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test - version managed from 1.1; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.1.5.RELEASE:test - version managed from 3.2.8.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:4.1.5.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |     \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.1.5.RELEASE:test - version managed from 3.2.8.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:jar:1.2.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:1.2.2.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator:jar:1.2.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:1.2.2.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:1.2.2.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.4.5:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.1.5.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 3.2.8.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.1.5.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 3.2.8.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.1.5.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 3.2.8.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- org.flywaydb:flyway-core:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.mockito:mockito-all:jar:1.10.19:compile
[INFO] +- com.h2database:h2:jar:1.4.185:compile
[INFO] +- mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:5.1.34:compile
[INFO] +- org.codehaus.janino:janino:jar:2.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.codehaus.janino:commons-compiler:jar:2.6.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.poi:poi:jar:3.10-FINAL:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.5:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:jar:3.10-FINAL:compile
[INFO] |  +- (org.apache.poi:poi:jar:3.10-FINAL:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml-schemas:jar:3.10-FINAL:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:jar:2.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- stax:stax-api:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |     \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.0.b2:compile
[INFO] \- org.scala-lang:scala-library:jar:2.10.4:compile
```

Comment: Can you tell the version of spring security & spring boot you using.

Comment: @Avis - Updated the question with maven deps tree. I am using Spring-Boot 1.2.2 and Spring Security 3.2.6.

Comment: Can you provide code for UserDetailsService as well !!!

Comment: @Avis, thanks for helping. I added UserDetailsService.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pls try this :-

a) Change

```
 @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
```

To

```
@Autowired
    private UserServiceBean userDetailsService;
```

b) Use @Service here

```
@Service
public class UserServiceBean implements UserService {
```

c) Change **@AuthenticationPrincipal User user** to **@AuthenticationPrincipal UserDetails userDetails**

Comment: UserServiceBean is already a Service and if I attempt to Autowire UserServiceBean instead of UserDetailsService I get NoSuchBeanDefinitionException.

Comment: Can you try point (c) above as well. Its just some wiring/bean issue thats resulting in NULL.

Comment: point (C) worked! Do you have any idea why I need to inject UserDetails instead of User? This is different from what the documentation states and what has worked for other users.

Comment: Bcoz you returning it => public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username), and as User is resolving to NULL so i felt User object is not of spring security so we left with UserDetails interface only which is of spring security.

Comment: To add this answer: The [Javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.0.3.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/bind/support/AuthenticationPrincipalArgumentResolver.html) (which I read _after_ this answer :) ) explicitly states: "If the types do not match, null will be returned unless AuthenticationPrincipal.errorOnInvalidType() is true in which case a ClassCastException will be thrown." Pretty strange that the error is not the default.

Comment: @WimDeblauwe If you turn this comment into an answer, I'll vote up

Comment: @lilalinux answer added.

Answer (score 6):

The type in the controller needs to match with the type that you return from the `UserDetailsService`.

The [Javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.0.3.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/bind/support/AuthenticationPrincipalArgumentResolver.html) explicitly states:

> If the types do not match, `null` will be returned unless
>   `AuthenticationPrincipal.errorOnInvalidType()` is `true` in which case a
>   `ClassCastException` will be thrown.

Pretty strange that the error is not the default.

Comment: There's also a bug in Spring Boot DevTools which triggers this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35156390/authenticationprincipal-with-spring-boot-not-working https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/5071

Comment: Thanks!
If anyone is having the same problem, a simple breakpoint the method below will help:
org.springframework.security.web.method.annotation.AuthenticationPrincipalArgumentResolver.resolveArgument

Comment: @Thiago That helped me solve it thank you! I'd changed to use JWT authentication so a `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` was being passed through instead of a `UserDetails` object.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is that you did not set `UserDetails` correctly for `Principal` field in the `Authentication` class.

`@AuthenticationPrincipal` is an abbreviation for `(UserDetails)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()`.

Try to print/debug the value of `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()` in your controller

For example:

```java
@GetMapping("/all")
public ResponseEntity<String> test(@AuthenticationPrincipal AuthUserDetails userDetails) {
 
    System.out.println(SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal());

    return ResponseEntity.ok("success");

}
```

If you get something other then the `UserDetails` object (e.g. a string), it means that you did not set `Principal` correctly when you are initializing your Authentication in the filter class. Let's use `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` as an example:

```java
// in filter class

@Component
public class JwtFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    private JwtProvider jwtProvider;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        Optional<AuthUserDetails> authUserDetailOptional = jwtProvider.resolveToken(request); // extract jwt from request, generate a userdetails object

        if (authUserDetailOptional.isPresent()){
            AuthUserDetails authUserDetails = authUserDetailOptional.get();
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                    authUserDetails, // set your authUserDetails here!!
                    null,
                    authUserDetails.getAuthorities()
            ); // generate authentication object

            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication); 
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        } else {
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "The token is not valid.");

        }

}
```