# @AuthenticationPrincipal with Spring Boot not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-boot

Using Spring Boot 1.3.1, I am having problems with `@AuthenticationPrincipal`.

This is my controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/user")
public class UserController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public UserDto user(@AuthenticationPrincipal(errorOnInvalidType = true) User user) {
        return UserDto.fromUser(user);
    }
}
```

This is my custom User class:

```
@Entity()
@Table(name = "app_user")
public class User extends AbstractEntity<UserId> implements Serializable {
// ------------------------------ FIELDS ------------------------------

    @NotNull
    @Column(unique = true)
    @Pattern(regexp = "[a-zA-Z_\\-\\.0-9]+")
    @Size(min = 1, max = 20)
    private String username;
    private String password;
    @Column(unique = true)
    @Email
    private String emailAddress;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @NotNull
    private UserRole role;
}
```

I also created a class to confirm to the `UserDetails` interface of Spring Security:

```
public class CustomUserDetails extends User implements UserDetails {

    public CustomUserDetails(User user) {
        super(user);
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return Sets.newHashSet(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + getRole().name()));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Then in my `UserDetailsService`:

```
@Override
public CustomUserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    com.company.app.domain.account.User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);

    if (user != null) {
        return new CustomUserDetails(user);
    } else {
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException(format("User %s does not exist!", username));
    }
}
```

I have an integration test that works perfectly. However, running the application itself (from IntelliJ IDEA), does not work. I get an exception:

```
"CustomUserDetails{id=UserId{id=401868de-99ff-4bae-bcb6-225e3062ed33}} is not assignable to class com.company.app.domain.account.User"
```

But this is not true, since `CustomUserDetails` is a subclass of my custom `User` class.

Checking with the debugger, I see that this code in `AuthenticationPrincipalArgumentResolver` fails:

```
if (principal != null
            && !parameter.getParameterType().isAssignableFrom(principal.getClass())) {
```

The classloader of `parameter.getParameterType()` is an instance of `RestartClassloader`, while `principal.getClass()` has a classloader that is an instance of `Launcher$AppClassLoader`.

Is this a bug in Spring Boot or Spring Security or am I doing something wrong?

*UPDATE:*

I can confirm that disabling devtools of Spring Boot makes it work:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.setProperty("spring.devtools.restart.enabled", "false");
    SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To help anyone else who hits the same problem, this is a limitation in Spring Boot DevTools and Spring Security OAuth. It's being tracked in this issue: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/5071

Comment: As a workaround, use the `InMemoryTokenStore` instead of the `JDBCTokenStore`