# How retrieve the user details in Spring Security

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

I am writing a Spring web application. Regarding the authentication, I'm using Spring Security , i need to retreive the information detail of the user , how to avoid that ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8764545/how-to-get-active-users-userdetails

Answer (score 0):

The path is *SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()*

This is for you as an example:

```
public UserDetails getCurrentUserDetails() {
        org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContext securityContext = SecurityContextHolder
                .getContext();
        Authentication authentication = securityContext.getAuthentication();
        UserDetails user = null;
        if (authentication != null) {
            if (authentication.getPrincipal() instanceof UserDetails)

            {
                user = ((UserDetails) authentication.getPrincipal());
            }
        }
        return user;
    }
```