# Clean way to bind @RequestParam to an object instead of a simple type

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-rest

I want to allow pagination in a REST API I am writing.  I would like to send requests as follows

```
GET /people?page[number]=1page[size]=25
```

or maybe

```
GET /people?page.number=1page.size=25
```

- The request above is just an example of what I am trying to do, if you know of a cleaner way to send the request please advise.

Then

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/people", params = { "page" })
public void findAll(@RequestParam("page") PaginationInformation paginationInformation) { 

}
```

`PaginationInformation` is just a plain old pojo with `number` and `size` getters and setters.

Is something like this possible in the latest version of Spring?  I realise I can just pass `pageNumber` and `pageSize` and bind as integers but I would rather use and object as I want to also support filtering which will be much more complex.

Comment: Spring Data does have a built-in `Pageable` with ready-made mappers and repository support.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can bind request parameters to custom model objects in Spring like this:

```
public class Page {
    private int pageOffset;
    private int pageSize;

    // Getters and setters omitted
}

@RequestMapping("/people")
public void findAll(Page page) {
}
```

If you send request like `GET /foo?pageOffset=0&pageSize=25` then the `page` parameter will be populated with those values. Notice also that there is no `@RequestParam` annotation.

Resolved `Page` object will be provided to the handler by [`ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor.html) under the hood, so feel free to look at its source code for more details.

If you need more flexibility in customizing the resolution of paging parameters, you can implement custom `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver`. You may use [`PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/web/PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver.java) from [Spring Data JPA](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#core.web.basic.paging-and-sorting) as an inspiration if you decide to go this way (or use Spring Data JPA for your persistence layer).

Comment: This looks good.  So when I have a `FilterInformation` object I will be able to supply two or more objects right? `public void findAll(Page page, Filters filters, Sort sort)` and prefix all field inside the filter pojo with fitlerXXX.  Does this sound correct?

Comment: @jax Yup, that should work. But just to be clear you mention `FilterInformation` and then `Filters` in your comment. Is that supposed to be one and the same class or different classes?

Comment: Yeah sorry, they're the same.

Answer (score 2):

Bohuslav Burghardt explained in his answer the most easy way: using a command-object / form-backing-object to pick the two parameters.
You explicit asked:

> Is something like this possible in the latest version of Spring?

Because I think the command-object way is well known, you asked for an other, more powerfull, way. Yes there is one (it exist since Spring 3.1).

**[`HandlerMethodArgumentResolver`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/method/support/HandlerMethodArgumentResolver.html).**

Because you have a special use case: Paging; I will not explain how exactly a `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` needs to be developed. Instead I recommend you to have a look at:

- the [code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/web/PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver.java) of  [`org.springframework.data.web.PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#core.web) from `spring-data-commons`, and
- its documentation: See "HandlerMethodArgumentResolvers for Pageable and Sort" in [Section 3.7.1. Web support](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#core.web).

*(maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8769670/280244) of mine helps you a bit in understanding how to deal with `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` and how to register them)*

So you can develop your own `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` or just use `PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver` form spring-data.