# Spring boot controller retrieve UserDetails

Tags: java, spring-boot, jwt

Hello so i have this method in JwtUtill

```
public Boolean validateToken(String token, UserDetails userDetails) {
    final String username = extractEmail(token);
    return (username.equals(userDetails.getUsername()) && !isTokenExpired(token));
}
```

But how can i request UserDetails in controller?

```
@GetMapping("/validateToken")
public String validateToken(@RequestHeader(value="token") String token) {
    if(jwtUtil.validateToken(token,???)) {

    }
}
```

Angular side

```
  public isTokenExpired(): Observable<string> {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('token', localStorage.getItem('token'));
    return this.httpClient.get<string>('http://localhost:8080/api/validateToken', {headers, responseType: 'text' as 'json'});
  }
```

Also as frontend im using angular

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get active user's UserDetails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8764545/how-to-get-active-users-userdetails)

Comment: It return null for me..

Comment: @angnewb It should be class which extends userdetails rather userdetails itself. You need to have user class which extends userdetails then you can pass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are using `jwt`, you don't need `UserDetails` to compare it with.

change methods as :

```java
public Boolean validateToken(String token) {
    final String username = extractEmail(token);
    return (!StringUtils.isEmpty(username) && !isTokenExpired(token));
}
```

```java
@GetMapping("/validateToken")
public String validateToken(@RequestHeader(value="token") String token) {
    if(jwtUtil.validateToken(token)) {

    }
}
```

> If your token is invalid you will not get exception in `extractEmail` method and if it is expired then method `isTokenExpired` will return `false`.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply inject it using [`@AuthenticationPrincipal`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/core/annotation/AuthenticationPrincipal.html). Eg:

```
@GetMapping("/validateToken")
public String validateToken(@AuthenticationPrincipal UserDetails userDetails, ...
```

Answer (score 0):

UserDetails comes in the security context in the principal

```
UserDetails userDetails =
 (UserDetails)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
```